# Adaptive Payments Permission Levels

Tags: paypal, credit-card, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a few questions about some functionalities of Adaptive Payments, which I am going to split in separate posts. Here is one:

I need to accept payments from guest senders who will pay with debit/credit card and chain the payment to a primary and a secondary Paypal account holders receivers.
By reading the [Documentation | PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) I noticed there are permission levels for setting a `fundingConstraint`, but I couldn't be able to find where and how I can enable those permissions.

Does a `fundingConstraint` apply for guest senders? How do I get the required permission levels? Can this be used so the sender is not asked to login into Paypal?

Any help will be appreciated.